# Convert columnar data to groups

Tags: r

How can I convert a data frame in the form

```
x  y
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

to

```
value group
  1     x
  2     x
  3     x
  4     y
  5     y
  6     y
```

for a function that is expecting grouped data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at `stack`:

```
> dat <- data.frame(x = 1:3,y = 4:6)
> dat
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
> stack(dat)
  values ind
1      1   x
2      2   x
3      3   x
4      4   y
5      5   y
6      6   y
```

I suppose I should add the "fancier" answer, which would be `melt` from the **plyr** package.

Answer (score 1):

I think @joran's answer is better but this would also do the job:

```
with(dat, data.frame(values =c(x,y), ind=rep(names(dat), each=nrow(dat) ) ) )
```